# How to Simulate a hung thread in a multi threaded environment?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

We have a Java multi threaded environment processing millions of records. In production, some threads have been observed to be hung, waiting for a synchronized method.. Work around was provided by removing dependency on synchronized method.

But, still unable to replicate the issue in Dev environment, that multiple threads are hung on a synchronized method. In Dev, all threads are completed in every attempt. Any suggestions how to replicate the issue in Dev to unit test the patch??

After more analysis, it seems the case of starvation.Any pointers on how to simulate starvation in executor framework ?

Comment: a thread dump (jstack) from the prod. environment would have helped to find the cause of blocking (was it a livelock, deadlock) Thant information will then help to replicate.

Comment: could you give a little more detail, such as the code where the threads are calling the synchronized method and the code for that method?

Comment: I personally don't see much use in simulating a hung thread here. You already know that the threads are "waiting for a synchronized method" what you need to do is find why they aren't able to enter the synchronized method (there's always another thread in the synchronized method before they can get in?). Simulating one thread hanging in the method will just make the other threads wait to enter the method, nothing learned.

Comment: "there's always another thread in the synchronized method before they can get in?"   Right.. Thousands of threads are running and some threads happen to be starve for the sync method... LiveLock or Deadlock ?? Actually, it more of starvation..How can we simulate starvation in executor framework.?

Answer (score 1):

In your DEV environment as you could not create a production like environment  to re-create the bug you need to introduce a long sleep statement in the synchronize block, so that other threads must wait for a thread to complete that synchronize block. So just add a long sleep statement inside your synchronize block and try.

Comment: Thanks for the input.There is a sync method which does its task and all threads wait for their turn and completes in dev environment. Any other suggestion to force a thread to wait for a sync method?

Comment: First following my idea put a long sleep. And let me know I will help you.